# Column strange behaviour when it has a child with aspectRatio modifier

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I put a composable (for example `text`) that has a fixed aspect in a column with two other composables, they all appear fine, as in this example:

```
@Preview()
@Composable
fun ColumnWithPrev() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp, 400.dp).background(Color.White),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        Text(
            "Text 1",
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green)
        )
        Text(
            "Text 2", textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).aspectRatio(1f)
        )
        Text(
            "Text 3",
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

[image: screen capture 1]

But when I change the size of the root container (`Column`) to be in landscape shape size(width = 200.dp, height = 400.dp) the `Column` will omit completely rendering 'Text 3' which is after the composable that has a set for `aspectRatio` as in the following code:

```
@Preview()
@Composable
fun ColumnWithPrev() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.size(400.dp, 200.dp).background(Color.White),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        Text(
            "Text 1",
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green)
        )
        Text(
            "Text 2", textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).aspectRatio(1f)
        )
        Text(
            "Text 3",
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

You can see here `Text 3` is missing:
[image: screen capture 2]

Some points to note:

- I am not setting a fixed height or width to `text 2`
- If you move 'Text 3' before 'Text 2' it will show up correctly

I am excepting a solution that makes:

- `text 3` appears below `text 2` even if the container size aspect ratio is landscape
- I want `Text 2` (Red Square) to take the maximum available horizontal space and respects the existence `Text 1` and `Text 3` above and below it
- I want `Text 1` and `Text 3` to be aligned vertically in the center of the white spaces available to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composable with the `aspectRatio` will be sized to occupy maximum available space while maintaining the aspect ratio. In the first case `Text 2` size is limited by column's width, in the second case it's limited by the height left available after measuring `Text 1`.

To keep `Text 3` visible and retain vertical arrangement, add a `weight` modifier to `Text 2` with `fill` param set to `false`.

```
Text(
    "Text 2", textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).weight(1f, false).aspectRatio(1f)
)
```

Why does it work? According to the `weight` modifier [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)):

> The parent will divide the vertical space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

That means that `Text 2` will be measured after `Text 1` and `Text 3` and will respect their sizes. Adding weights to the other Texts will work too.

Comment: Adding 'weight' to Text2 made Text3 appears in landscape size, but it caused the portrait size(200.dp, 400.dp) of column lose the proper arrangement of 'SpaceEvenly' so Text1 and Text3 appears at the top and bottom edges of the column, I want them to appear in the vertical middle of the top and bottom white spaces (as in the first image).

Comment: @RamezS It can be fixed by adding `fill = false` to `weight`. I edited the answer.

Comment: although it is not logical how the `fill` parameter on Text2 affected the horizontalAlignment of the other two elements, but it solved the problem. 
If you can explain why, that will help :)

Comment: @RamezS My guess is that when `Text 2` fills available height the fact that its shape is forced by `aspectRatio` doesn;t matter, these 2 modifiers don't interact this way.